# RE-entering UK on tourist visa after leaving just before ancestry visa expires

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, new-zealand-citizens

I am a NZ citizen who has been staying in the UK on an ancestry visa. I plan to leave the UK in March, just before my visa expires, and go to Eire for 6-8 weeks to visit friends. I would like to re-enter the UK for 2 weeks to say a final goodbye to friends here (I would already have my flight to NZ via Vietnam booked when I re-enter) is it possible for me to do this?

Comment: An option: Are you willing to [pay £649](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/extend-your-visa) to extend your visa?

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis that seems a bit excessive for an additional two weeks in the UK.

Comment: @phoog hence it is in a comment, not in the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. The second visit will be considered under "tourism". The official [GOV.UK page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/new-zealand/tourism) states the following:

> **You won’t need a visa to come to the UK**
>
> However, you should bring the same documents you’d need to apply for a visa, to show to officers at the UK border.
>
> **(!) You may want to apply for a visa if you have a criminal record or you’ve previously been refused entry into the UK.**

There is nothing prohibits you from visiting the UK again if you had a previous visa and they did not mention any time limit before you can come again to the UK.

Comment: Afaict if it was anywhere other than ireland this would be correct but "common travel area" rules complicate things.